# Installed SP Solution (custom Claims Provider) not installed to App Server - Security Token Service unavailable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In my farm I have two WFE's and two App Servers (or so I thought). I developed a Custom Claims Provider and installed to it to my farm. In the Solutions Store, I see that the solution was successfully deployed to my two WFE's and one of my app servers. My other app server isn't mentioned at all. Now on that other app server (call it app2), I'm seeing errors about the Security Token Service not being available. ULS log shows more details: It is unable to find the assembly for my custom Claims Provider. Well that makes sense since it didn't get deployed. My question is, can I ignore this error? We have the service running on the other machines so I'm guessing this is ok but I how do I supress it in the logs? Or is there a way to convince SharePoint that app02 is a WFE so that it can install the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Service on all servers in your farm. There is no reason to disable it.

Comment: What's weird is that my other app server doesn't have this service started, but the solution installed just fine. This did it for the troublesome server though, thanks!